# Cesar Cipher Decription using java

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am trying to decrypt this Cesar cipher using Java but cannot seem to get the code to decipher the code correctly using the key. I have used a for loop to iterate through all possible keys and print out the decrypted version. The decrypted text should have only capital letters in it.

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Main here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Main
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private String message;
    private int key;
    private int c;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Main
     */
    public Main()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        // y is 76 ascii
        message = "YMUMNINYMNNBYZYUMCVCFCNSIZNBYCLWIOHMYFNBCMCMNBYWBCYZNBCHAVYHINJYLNOLVYXMUCXNBYJUAUHGILUFCMNNBUNQUMDOMNWFULYMIQHIJCHCIHVONBYQUMJYLNOLVYXFYNHINSIOLBYULNVYNLIOVFYXHYCNBYLFYNCNVYUZLUCXMUCXNBYHUTULYHYWFULYWBCGYXCHWILXCUFFSVONBCMBYULNQUMNLIOVFYXUFFNBYMUGYBIQBYQIOFXBUPYFCEYXNIWIHZLIHNNBIMYNQIALYUNNBCHEYLMUHXYULHYMNFSUJJYUFNINBYGUMZYFFIQGUHNIZYFFIQGYHUHXUMENBYGNINYFFBCGNBYCLGYNBIXBCMGIIXNLUHMGONYXCNMYFZCHNIUXIAAYXCHXCZZYLYHWYNCFFUNFYHANBBYZUHWCYXBYQUMFIIECHAIHBCMIQHYRCMNYHWYQCNBNBYJUMMCPYCHNYLYMNIZUHIONMCXYLBYQUMYGVCNNYLYXVSNBYWIHPCWNCIHNBUNUFFNBCMXYMIFUNCIHBUXVYYHVLIOABNUVIONVSNBYUWWCXYHNIZBYLVYCHAUXOLVYLPCFFYQBYHBYZIOHXNBUNNYMMWUGYIZNBUNYRBUOMNYXUHWCYHNFCHYUHXQUMHINIZNBYHYQNLCVYMZLIGVYFIQUMBYBUXZIHXFSXLYUGYXQBSBUXBYHINMNICWUFFSUVUHXIHYXBYLCHZCXYFCNSNIBCMJLCHWCJFYMNBCMQUMQBUNBYBUXAINVSUJIMNUMSUHXBCMJOHCMBGYHNQUMXYMYLPYXNBYHBYVYWUGYQYUL";
        for(int a = 0; a<27; a++)
        {
            key = a;

            for(int i=0; i<message.length(); i++)
            {

                char ch;
                c = message.charAt(i)-key%23;
                ch =(char) (c);
                System.out.print(ch); 


            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    System.out.println("");

    }  
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are **26** letters in the English alphabet, so why is loop using **27**, and `%` remainder operator using **23**?

Comment: why loop the string and the alphabet. you just need to look at each character in the string and replace it with the shifted value.also in Cesar cipher  the key doesn't change.

Comment: @mavriksc OP doesn't know the cipher key, so the code tries all 26 possible keys. Attempt to break the encryption using brute-force.

Comment: Exactly i dont know what the key is so im using all possibilities of the key to break it. Also yeah I just reaised that I need a loop of 26 and there is someting to do with the modulous that is making code fail but cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to try out 26 keys and every time you leave the range of capital letters(<65) you add 26. Obviously the key you are looking for to decipher your message is 20.

```
    String message = "YMUMNINYMNNBYZYUMCVCFCNSIZNBYCLWIOHMYFNBCMCMNBYWBCYZNBCHAVYHINJYLNOLVYXMUCXNBYJUAUHGILUFCMNNBUNQUMDOMNWFULYMIQHIJCHCIHVONBYQUMJYLNOLVYXFYNHINSIOLBYULNVYNLIOVFYXHYCNBYLFYNCNVYUZLUCXMUCXNBYHUTULYHYWFULYWBCGYXCHWILXCUFFSVONBCMBYULNQUMNLIOVFYXUFFNBYMUGYBIQBYQIOFXBUPYFCEYXNIWIHZLIHNNBIMYNQIALYUNNBCHEYLMUHXYULHYMNFSUJJYUFNINBYGUMZYFFIQGUHNIZYFFIQGYHUHXUMENBYGNINYFFBCGNBYCLGYNBIXBCMGIIXNLUHMGONYXCNMYFZCHNIUXIAAYXCHXCZZYLYHWYNCFFUNFYHANBBYZUHWCYXBYQUMFIIECHAIHBCMIQHYRCMNYHWYQCNBNBYJUMMCPYCHNYLYMNIZUHIONMCXYLBYQUMYGVCNNYLYXVSNBYWIHPCWNCIHNBUNUFFNBCMXYMIFUNCIHBUXVYYHVLIOABNUVIONVSNBYUWWCXYHNIZBYLVYCHAUXOLVYLPCFFYQBYHBYZIOHXNBUNNYMMWUGYIZNBUNYRBUOMNYXUHWCYHNFCHYUHXQUMHINIZNBYHYQNLCVYMZLIGVYFIQUMBYBUXZIHXFSXLYUGYXQBSBUXBYHINMNICWUFFSUVUHXIHYXBYLCHZCXYFCNSNIBCMJLCHWCJFYMNBCMQUMQBUNBYBUXAINVSUJIMNUMSUHXBCMJOHCMBGYHNQUMXYMYLPYXNBYHBYVYWUGYQYUL";
    for(int a = -1; a<26; a++)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0; i<message.length(); i++)
            {
                char ch = message.charAt(i);
                int chAscii = (int) ch;
                chAscii -= a;
                if (chAscii < 65) {
                    chAscii = 26 + chAscii;
                }
                char newChar = (char) (chAscii);
                sb.append(newChar);
            }
            System.out.println("For key = "+a+" the message is "+sb.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why start at `-1`? Iterating range `-1` to `25`, inclusive, seems at bit strange.

Comment: My first step was that the first letter of the message is Y and you can either do minus -1 to make it Z or  minus 25 to make it A (and everything in between). Then in the second step I had to deal with other letters, where you get ouf of range and thus have to add +26.

Comment: You're right that `'Y' - -1` is `'Z'`, but `'Y' - 25` is `'@'`. To get `'A'` you need `'Y' - 24`. If that was your goal, it should be `for(int a = -1; a<25; a++)`, but since you have the `+ 26` logic anyway, it might as well be `for(int a = 0; a<26; a++)`, so the code is general, and not seemingly a brute force hack for messages starting with `Y`.

Answer (score 2):

```
c = message.charAt(i)-key%23;
```

should be

```
c = (message.charAt(i) - 'A' - key + 26) % 26 + 'A';
```

because:

- `message.charAt(i)` is a number between 65 (`A`) and 90 (`Z`)
- `message.charAt(i) - 'A'` is then a number between 0 and 25
- `key` should be a value between 0 and 25
- we want result to be positive, so `- key + 26` is a value between 1 and 26
- added together is a value between 1 and 51
- `(...) % 26` is then a value between 0 and 25
- and finally `... + 'A'` is a value between 65 (`A`) and 90 (`Z`)

Comment: Thanks for the help! The program is now returning all capital letter but im getting an error code saying "java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero" i think that with is something to do with the key becoming 0?

Comment: @OllieJones Since the only division/remainder operation is by a hardcoded `26`, I've no idea how you can get a division by zero exception.